# How to properly override method keys() while extending dict (in python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, extending

## EDIT: I added the class and some info, see the new post.

I have created a class that extends `dict` and `set` (more exactly, I extended `collections.abc.MutableMapping` and `MutableSet`). Now I want to properly override the method `keys()`.

This class represents a set of other objects, called `Measurand`:

```
class Measurands(MutableSet, MutableMapping):
    @property
    def measurands(self):
        return self._measurands
    
    
    @measurands.setter
    def measurands(self, val):
        self._measurands = []
        
        for el in val:
            self.add(el)
    
    
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        if arg is None:
            self.measurands = []
        else:
            try:
                measurands = arg.measurands
            except AttributeError:
                if isinstance(arg, Iterable):
                    measurands = list(arg)
                else:
                    measurands = [arg]
            
            self.measurands = measurands
            
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.measurands)
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for m in self:
            if m.id == key:
                return m
    
        raise KeyError(key)
    
    
    def __contains__(self, el_x):
        is_in = False
        
        for el in self:
            if el_x.id == el.id:
                is_in = True
                break
        
        return is_in
    
    
    def add(self, el):
        try:
            self[el.id].session_ids |= el.session_ids
        except KeyError:
            self[el.id] = Measurand(el)
    
    
    def _discard(self, key):
        res = False
        
        for i, m in enumerate(self):
            if m.id == key:
                del self.measurands[i]
                res = True
                break
        
        return res
    
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        res = self._discard(self, key)
        
        if not res:
            raise KeyError(key)
    
    def discard(self, key):
        self._discard(self, key)
    
    
    def remove(self, key):
        self.__delitem__(self, key)
    
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.measurands)
    
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        res = False
        value_true = Measurand(value)
        
        for i, m in enumerate(self):
            if m.id == key:
                res = True
                
                if value.id == key:
                    self.measurands[i] = value_true
                else:
                    raise KeyError(key)
                
                break
        
        if not res:
            self.measurands.append(value_true)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        string = "Measurands({"
        
        for m in self:
            string += str(m)
            string += ", "
        
        if string:
            string = string[:-2]
        
        string += "})"
        
        return string
```

The problem is the default method `keys` returns a "list" of `Measurand` objects. This is not what I want. The keys should be the property `id` of the `Measurand` objects.

For now I'm returning a simple `list`, but I would return a `dict_keys` or a `collection.abc.KeysView` object. Unluckily, `dict_keys` is not a global name.

1. Where is `dict_keys`?
2. Is this the correct/pythonic way to do it?

Comment: *"I want to properly override the method `dict()`"* - what? `dict` isn't a method. Do you mean you want to be able to do `dict(instance_of_your_thing)`? Could you give a [mcve] of your implementation and explain the problem with an example?

Comment: Judging from the title, I think he meant he wants to properly override `keys()` and made a typo in the actual question

Comment: @wilbur ah! That would make more sense. OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already handled for you! `collections.abc.MutableMapping` includes a reasonable default implementation of `keys` that provides the same interface as `dict.keys`.

Simply delete your `keys` method, and you'll be using the inherited implementation.

Comment: Well, I missed to report some useful info. See the updated question.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: It's not returning a list of Measurands. You've screwed up your `__iter__`; it's iterating over values instead of keys. Fix that, and the inherited `keys` implementation will work.

Comment: `__iter__` is correct. If I do `for m in mm` where `mm` is a `Measurands` object, I want that `m` is the i-th `Measurand` object, not its id. If you notice, the `Measurand` class is a mix of `set` and `dict` that I created because you can't do a `set` of unhashable objects.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: That's a violation of the mapping API, and if you're not going to follow the API, you shouldn't bother with `keys`, `values`, or `items`. They'll just cause confusion.

Comment: Not sure that it's a violation. Since I'm extending also `set`, I'm following the behaviour of `__iter__` of the `set` interface.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: You really shouldn't be extending MutableMapping at all. The mapping API specifies that iteration should iterate over keys and `in` should report whether the argument is a key. If you want iteration and `in` to work with values, you cannot comply with the mapping API. (Also, extending `MutableSet` or `MutableMapping` does not mean you extend `set` or `dict`.)

Comment: You're right. I'm not following the contract of both the `abc`s. I modified the class to iterate over keys and now `keys()`, `values()` and `items()` automagically work. I have to say anyway that I do not like the default behaviour of Python's (and many other languages) iteration over dictionaries. Iterating over lists does not return the index of the list. I can't understand why this must be different for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any way to cast something to the `dict_keys` type, but after reading the PEP that introduced the new way to access keys and values ([PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/)), it looks like `dict_keys` was introduced to

> return a set-like or unordered container object whose contents are derived from the underlying dictionary rather than a list which is a copy of the keys, etc.

Taking this into account, it looks like you could get away with returning a generator object with your `keys()` method instead of a list.

Here is the pseudo-code from the PEP:

```
class dict:

    # Omitting all other dict methods for brevity.

    def keys(self):
        return d_keys(self)

class d_keys:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__d = d

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__d)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.__d

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.__d:
            yield key
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python3 documentation says that `dict.keys()` return value type (i.e. a view) is "set-like", so your return value should be "set-like" as well.

> The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items()
>   are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s
>   entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view
>   reflects these changes.
>
> Dictionary views can be iterated over to yield their
>   respective data, and support membership tests:
>
> ....
>
> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.
>   If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and
>   hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not
>   treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For
>   set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base
>   class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

Full text here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views